# How can I understand MaterialUI styled component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make sense of how to inject styles into component with MaterialUI and I'm very confused! Can anyone please explain what I did wrong? i read the documentation but it honestly didn't make sense to me. What are classes? And how do I attach the const style into the component BeerList?

My code threw an error "Cannot read property of classes undefined. I know I must have pulled from the wrong props. But I don't know how to fix it...

```
 import React from 'react';
import BeerListItem from './BeerListItem';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import StarBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
     overflow: 'hidden',
     backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
    gridList: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      transform: 'translateZ(0)',
    },
    titleBar: {
      background:
        'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, ' +
        'rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)'
      },

    icon: {
      color: 'white',
    },
  });

const BeerList = ({beers}) =>{
const {classes} = beers;
    const beerItems = beers.map((beer) => {
        return <BeerListItem  key={beer.id} beer = {beer}/> 
      });
      return (<div className={classes.root} >
       <GridList cellHeight={250} spacing={1} >
      {beerItems}
      </GridList>
      </div>);
    };


export default withStyles(styles)(BeerList);
```

Comment: console the `beers` props. check what it is? then distructures `classes`

Comment: i did it. It was just a list of 20 beers. I read the documents on GridList and i don't understand what exactly the props in the const {classes}= props is, why not use, say, <div className = styles.icon></div> , but classes.icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes distructured from props.
you need a little change on your components like:

```
const BeerList = (props) =>{
const {classes, beers} = props;

  // rest of your code
  return <div className={classes.root} >
    <GridList cellHeight={250} spacing={1} >
      {beerItems}
    </GridList>
  </div>
};
```

That's it.

Comment: You saved me @Ikram! Thanks so much!!